# draw a line with a single point and length (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, line

How can I practically  draw a line in leaflet with following info:

1)its length,

2)starting point,

3)angle.

i.e., there is NO end point information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: calculate the end point by using the given values (simple trigonometry task), then construct the line object programmatically, using the start point and the calculated end point.

Given your generic style of question, that is all the answer I can give. Please expand on it (where exactly do you get stuck? Do you have an example?) if you need more help with this.

EDIT: How to create a polyline via the API is well-documented in Leaflet, and it's really simple as well:
http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#polyline

EDIT2 in response to comment:
I made an example for a simple trigonometric solution here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pmusx2wp/2/

Note that the 'angle' and 'length' here are flat and do not correspond to the actual shape of the globe.

Comment: Yes indeed the documentation is useful, BUT not in this issue. In fact,  I need a trigonometric example.

Comment: You are being very terse with information about what you need. What units is the length in? Is the second point to be geometrically correct (pure distance/angle), or cartographically correct, where there is no such thing as a straight line and math gets more complicated. In that case, the calculation would involve the (surface) distance and a bearing from the starting point. Also: Should the resulting line be a straight line between those points on the map projection, or indicate a shortest-surface-distance on a globe?

Comment: the resulting line  should  be a straight line between those points

Comment: LatLng 1 [44.67, 6.922] -- this is my first point.  Plus, I have a radius information of a circle (500px) which I planned to use as length of my line. Last, this radius is in pixels as it is by default in leaflet. @Senshi

Comment: I have a hard time figuring the intent of your application. A map is a presentation of a globe (in most cases), so a pixel distance cannot easily be applied to it (because pixels are two-dimensional). So you need a way to convert your pixels to the map projection units. Which is possible, but in which case the actual distance changes drastically with the angle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637023/how-to-calculate-the-latlng-of-a-point-a-certain-distance-away-from-another for an illustration of the issue, especially "how does a circle on the pole look like".

Comment: Please don't make unbased assumptions like that, it makes people unwilling to assist you further. I have worked with Leaflet on numerous occasions, and I have given you an example solution for your problem in the jsfiddle above. You came here for help, I tried to provide it. If you don't want help, then why ask in the first place. For your information: Pixels are certainly not "the default in Leaflet". Leaflet uses the EPSG3857 as CRS by default, and that's how coordinates and distances are handled. Pixels don't come into the equation, unless you use CRS.Simple for true flat maps?